# How to assign mesh to certain bones?

Tags: bones

[image]

Image shows it all, I'm trying to assign the teeth to the jaw bone but I'm new to blender and I don't know how rip

Answer (score 1):

For this I would assign the weights directly by going into edit mode, selecting the teeth, and assigning the weight to the jaw in the object data tab of the properties window:[image]

Don't forget to also remove the influence from other bones.

This works well for teeth because they move 100% with the jaw bone. For smoother things that are influenced by multiple bones you will need to use weight painting.